# Function series - pointwise/ uniform converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let the function series:$$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$  study it's converges (point-wise/uniform) in $\mathbb{R}$.

So we have: $$S(x) = x^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

Now, if I showed that for sufficiently large $n$-s for a given $x$:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$ then we're done.

For uniform converges, I think we can use dini's theorem but for that we need to know that $S(x)$ is a continuous function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\space\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\space\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\space\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^m}\right)=1-\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^m}=$$
$$1-\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(x^2+1\right)^{-m}=1-\lim_{m\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(x^2+1\right)^{-m}\right)\right)=$$
$$1-\lim_{m\to\infty}\exp\left(-m\ln\left(x^2+1\right)\right)=1-\exp\left(-\ln\left(x^2+1\right)\lim_{m\to\infty}m\right)=$$
$$1-\exp\left(-\ln\left(x^2+1\right)\lim_{m\to\infty}m\right)=1-0=1$$

So it equals $1$ when: $\frac{1}{|x^2+1|}<1$

---

With some strange notations (because $\infty$ isn't a number):

$$1-\exp\left(-\ln\left(x^2+1\right)\lim_{m\to\infty}m\right)=$$
$$1-\exp\left(-\ln\left(x^2+1\right)\cdot\infty\right)=$$
$$1-\exp\left(-\infty\right)=1-e^{-\infty}=1-\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=1-0=1$$

Comment: @Elimination You're welcome! If you know that $x$ is real you can find: $\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^n}=x^2\left(\left(x^2+1\right)^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$

Comment: @Elimination You're welcome (again)!